# How to update dir on SVN server

Tags: 12.04, svn

I need to update the whole directory content to svn project.

My svn project preset at location 
**/home/svn/baseproject**

And I want to update the directory present at location
**/var/www/baseproject/app/controllers/components**

Please tell how could I do it?

Please provide ubuntu terminal command to do it.

Comment: Waht do you mean with update? Do you like to add content of `/var/www/baseproject/app/controllers/components`to subversion and do version controll for it?

Comment: I have made changes in files present at location "var/www/baseproject/app/controllers/components". Now I just want to commit this whole directory on svn which present at local location "/home/svn/baseproject".

Answer (score -1):

One solution could be to make a working copy of your repository at e.g. /tmp. Commands like this should work:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ svn co file:///home/svn/baseproject
$ cp -r /var/www/baseproject/ /tmp/baseproject/
$ cd /tmp/baseproject
$ svn status
$ [svn add] # maybe
$ svn commit
```

You should really have also a look into subversion documentation for details

P.S. This is of course only working, if `/home/svn/baseproject` is your repository, not your working copy.

Comment: No its not work. And I think it is not the proper way to do it.

Comment: Why its not working as to stark working w/o a working copy is unfortunately not the default.

Comment: I've just tried it and it was working (ok, I needed to correct the cp command -> http://pastebin.geany.org/V03g9/)